# Method Post and Get In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter.

```
if(isset($query1))
{
    foreach($query1 as $row)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'site/companyDetail">'.$row->companyName.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->address.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->contactPerson.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->contactnum.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

I want to pass `$row->companyName` in the URL to be a part of `site/companyDetail?name=CompanyName` where `companyDetail` is a file. The values are from a SQL database. I want to load `companyDetail` of `CompanyName`. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part a bit more.

Comment: Now, that the companyName is at the URL, I have the file companyDetail and I want companyName to be passed to companyDetail. Then, I will have some SQL queries on it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Pass **`$row->companyName`** as parameter,

```
if(isset($query1))
{
    foreach($query1 as $row)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'site/companyDetail/"'.$row->companyName.'>'.$row->companyName.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->address.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->contactPerson.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->contactnum.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

2) After clicking on the link it'll reach your Controller **(applications/controllers/site.php)**,

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function companyDetail($companyName)
    {
       // Uncomment below to check whether you are getting company name
       // echo $companyName; exit;

       $data['company'] = $this->abc_model->get_company_details($companyName);

      // Uncomment below to check the data
      // echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); exit;

       $this->load->view('views/company_detail.php', $data);
    }
}
```

3) Your view **("applications/views/company_detail.php")**

```
<table>
<?php foreach($company as $c) { ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $c['name']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $c['founder']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $c['assets']; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You have to pass `$row->companyName` in your link (in `href`). Your link should look like this `http://www.example.com/site/companyDetail/dell`

Comment: Hey. I got it now. But I can't seem to access the $companyName into the function. What should I do next?

Comment: I mean, I have the dell but can't use it in the function. I've already tried

$yes = $companyName;
echo $yes;

and $yes has no value.

Comment: Try echoing `$companyName` inside your function. Try, `public function companyDetail($companyName)
    {
        echo $companyName; exit;
    }`

Comment: Now, how do I put it in the view except for using echo? I can't seem to find a way over it.

Comment: Actually, I am now in the process of decoding the companyName. Thanks a lot!